# I am getting the same error for whatever I am trying to install. How to fix this unmet dependency and broken package ?

Tags: package-management, wine, 17.10, vlc

I am currently trying to install wine and previously have failed to install VLC on Ubuntu 17.10. I have tried almost all the solutions available on other forums.

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libvlc5 : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180102+r73456+113~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
     vlc : Depends: vlc-bin (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
           Depends: vlc-plugin-qt (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
           Depends: vlc-plugin-video-output (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: vlc-l10n (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180102+r73456+113~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: vlc-plugin-skins2 (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: vlc-plugin-video-splitter (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
           Recommends: vlc-plugin-visualization (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180123+r73755+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1 is to be installed
     vlc-plugin-base : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
     vlc-plugin-notify : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
     vlc-plugin-qt : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
                     Recommends: vlc-bin but it is not going to be installed
     vlc-plugin-samba : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
     vlc-plugin-skins2 : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
                         Recommends: vlc-bin but it is not going to be installed
     vlc-plugin-video-output : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
     vlc-plugin-video-splitter : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
     vlc-plugin-visualization : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180122+r73743+120~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Looks like you failed more than once to install VLC, and perhaps failed to clean up after the first try...which then broke the second try. Tell us more about all your tries to install VLC, and please link to the instructions you followed.

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested to you ? `apt --fix-broken install`?